# Tayamum a ritual cleaning

Tags: taharah, tayammum

It is necessary to wipe all part of your face means if we mistakely not move hand on very small area of face does tayamum become invalid

Answer (score 1):

No. You must reach all.
https://youtu.be/zrhZQ1l0NZg
Check out the way its done.